# Uploading photos to instagram, using php

Tags: instagram-api

Is it possible to upload photos from a webpage to Instagram, if so how do you do it?

I am wondering how to do this, so I can have a website where people can vote on their favourite photo and the one with most votes will be posted each day!

Comment: Nice idea! Can you post some php code you have tried?

Comment: not possible, read API documentation